# How do I create and query linked database servers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to do a join across two different database servers (IPs 10.0.0.50 and 10.0.0.51). What's the best way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use sp_linkedserver to create a linked server.

```
sp_addlinkedserver [ @server= ] 'server' [ , [ @srvproduct= ] 'product_name' ] 
 [ , [ @provider= ] 'provider_name' ]
 [ , [ @datasrc= ] 'data_source' ] 
 [ , [ @location= ] 'location' ] 
 [ , [ @provstr= ] 'provider_string' ] 
 [ , [ @catalog= ] 'catalog' ]
```

More information available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx).

Comment: Yeah -- it's one of those things where I figured the answer was out there, just wanted to store the howto in stack overflow :)

Answer (score 22):

The solution I found:

1) Run a [stored proc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259589(SQL.80).aspx)

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver    @server='10.0.0.51'
```

2) Verify that the servers were linked (lists linked servers)

```
exec sp_linkedservers
```

3) Run the query using the format

```
 [10.0.0.51].DatabaseName.dbo.TableName
```

Answer (score 21):

I know that the answers above are good, but wanted to share some details that I hope others will find helpful. Worth to mention is the user access part, which I think people will need help with.

**set up the link:**

`exec sp_addlinkedserver  @server='10.10.0.10\MyDS';`

**set up the access for remote user, example below:**

`exec sp_addlinkedsrvlogin  '10.10.0.10\MyDS', 'false', null, 'adm', 'pwd';`

**see the linked servers and user logins:**

`exec sp_linkedservers;`

`select * from sys.servers;`

`select * from  sys.linked_logins;`

**run the remote query:**

`select * from [10.10.0.10\MyDS].MyDB.dbo.TestTable;`

**drop the linked server and the created login users (adm/pwd)**

`exec sp_dropserver '10.10.0.10\MyDS', 'droplogins'; -- drops server and logins`

**resources:**

[sp_addlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx)

[sp_dropserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174310.aspx)

[sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

[sp_droplinkedsrvlogin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186218.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

You can, as mentioned, use sp_addlinkedserver. However, you may also do this via Enterprise Manager (2000) or SQL Server Management Studio (2005). Under the "Security" node, there is a "Linked Servers" node, which you can use to add and configure Linked Servers. You can specify security settings, impersonation, etc.

See these for SQL Server 2000:

[Configuring Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778(SQL.80).aspx)

[Establishing Security For Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213768(SQL.80).aspx)

[Configuring OLEDB Providers for Distributed Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213787(SQL.80).aspx)

See these for SQL Server 2005:

[Linking Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279(SQL.90).aspx)

[Security for Linked Servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175537(SQL.90).aspx)

[Configuring Linked Servers for Delegation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189580(SQL.90).aspx)

[Configuring OLEDB Providers for Distributed Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190918(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: In SQLServer 2012 this node has been moved to "Server Objects"