# Import data from one DB to another Database with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have no clue how to Import data from one database to another with condition.

I have DB Name (Northwind) and the table Name Employee

I have following columns

ID 
Name

I have another DB (Mater) and the table Name Employee.

I have the following columns
Emp.ID
Emp.Name

Now i want transfer all data from Northwind.Employee to  Master.Employee table with Condition.

Condition is

IF ID=1 then Emp.ID=201 (this is a constant value no logic behind that)

Any idea or suggestion please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use a `case` statement in your `insert`:

```
insert into master.schema.employee (id, name)
select case when id = 1 then 201 else id end, name
from northwind.schema.employee
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to select from diferent DB you can assist this question:
[INSERT INTO from two different server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153657/insert-into-from-two-different-server-database)

the id issue is a simple case you can see example here: [SQL Case Statement Syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622/sql-case-statement-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

if the databases are on the same server, you can just reference the 2 tables from the different databases with SQL such as the following:

```
INSERT INTO Master.Employee 
SELECT 201 as ID, e2.Name
FROM Northwind.Employee e2
WHERE e2.ID = 1
```

But if the databases are on different servers, you will have to use either a linked server or SSIS package to achieve this.