# Data Insertion from one sql server to another

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am working on Microsoft SQL server databases. I have a base database and a application database. What I want to push some data (using query) from application db to base database on some specific time period. Is this can be achieved by db procedure?

Both database are at different location in context of IP. Is there any way for connection between db at DB level?

Comment: I didn't found any solution so far. So tried nothing.

Comment: @parth.hirpara, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189422/how-do-i-create-and-query-linked-database-servers-in-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linked server:

[How do I create and query linked database servers in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189422/how-do-i-create-and-query-linked-database-servers-in-sql-server)

As for running the query on a timer, you can do that with an agent, or from within your application, or a scheduled task, etc.